Keep div scroll to button did not work as expect in React
I have a React component like this (the Node version is 18):
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import "./App.css";

export interface IChatAskList {
  myMap: Map<string, string>;
}

const App: React.FC<IChatAskList> = (props: IChatAskList) => {

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, []);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  }  

  const renderChat = () => {
    const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
    props.myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
        tagList.push(
          <div className="chat-message">
            {value}
          </div>
        );
    });
    return tagList;
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat-list-body">
      <button onClick={scrollToBottom}>Scroll to Button</button>
      {renderChat()}
      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


And this is the parent component Home.tsx:
import { useState } from "react";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";

const Home: React.FC = () => {

  const [element, setElement] = useState<Map<string, string>>(new Map<string, string>());


  const add = () => {
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

    setElement(prevState => {
        const newState = new Map(prevState); 
        newState.set(currentTime, 'long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text.......'); 
        return newState;
      });
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={add}>add</button>
      <App myMap={element} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;

And this is the App.css:
.chat-list-body{
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}

Now I want the chat-list-body div always scroll to button when props.myMap changed(click the add button). I have tried to add useEffect in App.tsx like this:
React.useEffect(() => {
    // debugger
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [props.myMap]);

I also tried to add a button, when click the button, chat-list-body scroll to button works, and will scroll to top when  props.myMap changed. How to make the chat-list-body div always scroll to button(like the chat view, the newest message always show in button and the view always keep scroll to button)? Am I missing something? When I tried to use the setTimeout like this:
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            scrollToBottom();
        }
        .bind(this),
        1000
    );
  });

it works. But the div scroll to top when myMap changed. I also tried useLayoutEffect like this:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import "./App.css";

export interface IChatAskList {
  myMap: Map<string, string>;
}

const App: React.FC<IChatAskList> = (props: IChatAskList) => {

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, []);

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  }  

  const renderChat = () => {
    const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
    props.myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
        tagList.push(
          <div className="chat-message">
            {value}
          </div>
        );
    });
    return tagList;
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat-list-body">
      <button onClick={scrollToBottom}>Scroll to Button</button>
      {renderChat()}
      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

did not work. Finally I found the scroll to button works with plain context, when the item contains ReactMarkdown component, the scroll to button did not work, seems the scroll did not contains the ReactMarkdown code height.


Please create a [mre].

useLayoutEffect here instead of useEffect.
